# Retrieving element from tuple inside tuple based on some condition

Tags: python, tuples

I have data structure like this as below,

```
def fun():
    print "fun"
d=[('File',(('save',fun),('saveas',fun),)),
        ('Edit',('search',fun))]
```

Given input like this say

> input = "File.save.saveas'

I want to retrieve the associated function of the last string inside the whole string. Here 'saveas' function

How do I get that function?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a typical XY problem. What you want is a dictionary, not that super weird nested tuple.

Comment: yes. But the problem is I get data structure in such weird format. I need generic way to get associated function no matter what the data structure is based on the string.

Comment: I tried converting that tuple into dictionary. But it didn't help. I get this error 'dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required' since tuple might come with more than two values.

Comment: Are you sure you showed the correct definitions of variables `d` and `input`? Your `input` implies that `saveas` comes under `save` but it is actually at the same level inside `d`

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps:

- You can use `str.split` to split the user input on the `.` separator.
- Access the first field with `[0]` and the last field with `[-1]`.
- Loop over the major options until you find a match.
- Loop over the minor options until you find a match.
- If no match is found, raise a *ValueError*.

Here is one way to code it:

```
def save_it():
    print 'Saving'

def edit_it():
    print 'Edit'

menu = [
    ('File', (
      ('save', save_it),
      ('saveas', save_it),
      )),
    ('Edit', (
      ('search', edit_it),
      )),
]

def dispatch(user_input):
    fields = user_input.split('.')
    major_choice = fields[0]
    minor_choice = fields[-1]

    for major, minors in menu:
        if major == major_choice:
            for minor, func in minors:
                if minor == minor_choice:
                    func()
                    return
            raise ValueError('No matching minor option: %r' % minor_choice)
    raise ValueError('No matching major option: %r' % major_choice)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dispatch('File.save.saveas')
    dispatch('Edit.search')
    dispatch('Edit.cut')
```